# Headings in source blocks

Tags: org-mode

I tried to export an org source block containing a heading.

My first attempt,

```
#+NAME: rekotor 
#+BEGIN_SRC org :exports none
* KOTOR and KOTOR 2 are the only worthwhile products of the Star Wars franchise
#+END_SRC 

* List of heresies
  #+CALL: rekotor[:results silent :exports results]
```

resulted in an error.

It turns out that to call the `rekotor` source block under a heading, I had to ident the heading within the `rekotor` block. Like this,

```
#+NAME: rekotor 
#+BEGIN_SRC org :exports none
  ** KOTOR and KOTOR 2 are the only worthwhile products of the Star Wars franchise
#+END_SRC.
```

I also had to start the `#+CALL` at column index 0,

```
* List of heresies
#+CALL: rekotor[:results silent :exports results].
```

Only then the export (to LaTeX) worked.

While this question/answer is primarily aimed as a reminder to myself in case I forget about this, I am wondering is there a more elegant fashion of embedding headings defined in org source blocks in the main org document body?

Comment: Have you tried to mask the heading with a comma like that `,* KOTOR and KOTOR 2 are the only worthwhile products of the Star Wars franchise`?

Comment: I do not know what a comma is supposed to do. I just tried replacing ** with ,* and this produced a top-level heading, instead of subheading. Actually, I just checked, the comma seems to be completely ignored.

Comment: `,** KOTOR and KOTOR 2 are the only worthwhile products of the Star Wars franchise` should produce a subheading. `,` is telling org-mode to not interpret `*` as an heading in the org-mode file -- otherwise it would mess up the source block. If you tangle the source block, the comma should be dropped.